# NSURLConnection to pull text from website only gets some of the data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to pull some data from a webpage. I have it partially working, but it is only pulling a snippet of HTML from this webpage rather than all of it. Here is my implementation code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://waterdata.usgs.gov/ga/nwis/uv?cb_72036=on&cb_00062=on&format=gif_default&period=1&site_no=02334400"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        // Connect

        label.text = @"Connecting...";
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
    label.text = response;
    connection = nil;
}
```

What do I need to do to get the whole page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`didReceiveData:` pulls in chunks to ensure not only the fastest downloading, but the potential to download massive files without having a 2GB NSData object and crashing the application for taking up too much memory.

What you want to do is create an `NSMutableData` instance variable.

Allocate and initialize it either in the init method of your view controller or when the connection starts.

In `didReceiveData:` you are going to simply append the data to your `NSMutableData`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [myData appendData:data];
}
```

Then in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
    response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    label.text = response;
}
```

You can actually remove response as an instance variable in this case (unless you need it later).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still not working. Here is my code...     ' - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [myData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection {
    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
        
    connection = nil;
} '

Comment: Sorry, for the terrible formatting, I tried to use the mini-markdown and indicate it was code, but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh, like I said above, you want to make myData an instance variable, then initialize it in `initWithNibName:bundle:` or `connectionDidReceiveResponse:` the reason why it doesn't work in your updated code is because you're effectively creating a new NSMutableData every time it receives the next snippet, overwriting your last one. The only thing that should be in `didReceiveData:` is the `appendData:`

Comment: This is EXACTLY the problem I had, thank you for the answer Kevin Low.

Answer (score 0):

`connection:didReceiveData:` is called every time more data arrives, not necessarily only once. So rather than creating a new string every time and throwing away the original (which will leak if you're not using the ARC compiler) you probably want to create a new string and append it to your current working results. E.g.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
newResponse = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[response appendString:newResponse];

}
```

Assuming `response` is a mutable string you've created beforehand and I've added an `autorelease` in case you're not using the ARC compiler.

If you're using iOS 5 you should also seriously consider using [`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) instead of the older delegate route, as it makes your code simpler and more readable.